# git remote server moved, how to update working copy configuration?

Tags: git, git-remote

Here is my current set up

```
 FDMBA:EnglishStudy willentriken$ git remote -v
 origin root@devel.phor.net:~/repos/echo.git (fetch)
 origin root@devel.phor.net:~/repos/echo.git (push)
```

But we changed the hostname of the server from devel.phor.net to something else. Can I "repoint" my local git repository to point to this new server address without losing any of the local commits, etc. that I have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, just use the `set-url` command

```
git remote set-url origin root@newhost:repo/echo.git
```

You can see the result

```
git remote -v
origin root@newhost:repo/echo.git (fetch)
origin root@newhost:repo/echo.git (push)
```